# How to give sequence number of list items and create dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list and I want to give sequence number to every item and create a dataframe after that. Please help me how can I do this?

Example:

```
lst = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt', 'file5.txt', 'file6.txt', 'file7.txt', 'file8.txt', 'file9.txt', 'file10.txt', 'file11.txt', 'file12.txt', 'file13.txt', 'file14.txt', 'file15.txt']
```

I have to give sequence number like this-

```
df:

filename       sequence
file1.txt       1
file2.txt       1
file3.txt       2
file4.txt       2
file5.txt       3
file6.txt       3
file7.txt       4
file8.txt       4
file9.txt       5
file10.txt      5
file11.txt      6
file12.txt      6
file13.txt      7
file14.txt      7
file15.txt      8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
lst = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt', 'file5.txt', 'file6.txt', 'file7.txt', 'file8.txt', 'file9.txt', 'file10.txt', 'file11.txt', 'file12.txt', 'file13.txt', 'file14.txt', 'file15.txt']

df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': lst, 'sequence': [x // 2 + 1 for x in range(len(lst))]})
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

      filename  sequence
0    file1.txt         1
1    file2.txt         1
2    file3.txt         2
3    file4.txt         2
4    file5.txt         3
5    file6.txt         3
6    file7.txt         4
7    file8.txt         4
8    file9.txt         5
9   file10.txt         5
10  file11.txt         6
11  file12.txt         6
12  file13.txt         7
13  file14.txt         7
14  file15.txt         8
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['filename'])
```

Finally:

```
df['sequence']=(df.index//2)+1
```

**OR**

```
df=pd.DataFrame([lst,[x//2+1 for x in range(len(lst))]],index=['filename','sequence']).T
```

**OR**

```
df=pd.DataFrame(zip(lst,[x//2+1 for x in range(len(lst))]),columns=['filename','sequence'])
```

**OR**

```
df=(pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['filename'])
     .assign(sequence=[x//2+1 for x in range(len(lst))]))
```

Comment: Elegant one as usual

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want, you can just create a list of those sequences and then create the dataframe out of the file list and the sequence list.

```py
sequence = []
for i in range(1, len(lst)//2+2):
    sequence += [i, i]
df = pd.DataFrame({'fileName':lst, 'sequence':sequence[:len(lst)]})
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
      fileName  sequence
0    file1.txt         1
1    file2.txt         1
2    file3.txt         2
3    file4.txt         2
4    file5.txt         3
5    file6.txt         3
6    file7.txt         4
7    file8.txt         4
8    file9.txt         5
9   file10.txt         5
10  file11.txt         6
11  file12.txt         6
12  file13.txt         7
13  file14.txt         7
14  file15.txt         8
```